# How can I undo an etoolbox patch?

Tags: etoolbox

Suppose I patch an environment using an [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) command such as `\AtBeginEnvironment` or `\AfterEndEnvironment`, etc. How can I undo these changes at a later stage?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\olditemize\itemize 
\let\oldenditemize\enditemize
\AfterEndEnvironment{itemize}{bleat bleat}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is an item.
\end{itemize}
\let\itemize\olditemize        %Would like to undo the change
\let\enditemize\oldenditemize  %now, but this doesn't help.
\begin{itemize}
\item This is another item.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all note that `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment` does not patch the environment itself. It only adds material to hooks. `etoolbox` patches usage of these hooks to `\begin` and `\end`. That's the reason why resetting `\itemize` and `\enditemize` to their original definitions does not change anything.

But you may simply *undefine* the environment end hook of `itemize`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{itemize}{bleat bleat}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is an item.
\end{itemize}

\csundef{@afterend@itemize@hook}% undefine the end hook of itemize
\begin{itemize}
\item This is another item.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

`\csundef` is a `etoolbox` command and `\@afterend@itemize@hook` is the environment end hook of environment `itemize`. The environment begin hook would be `\@beforebegin@itemize@hook`.

Maybe a feature request for commands like `\CleanBeforeBeginEnvironment` or `\CleanAfterBeginEnvironment` could be suggested.

**Alternative:** If you only want to remove something but not everything, you may try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newrobustcmd*{\RemoveFromAfterEndEnvironment}[2]{%
  \expandafter\patchcmd\csname @afterend@#1@hook\endcsname{#2}{}%
}

\AfterEndEnvironment{itemize}{bleat bleat\par}{}{}
\AfterEndEnvironment{itemize}{don't remove this\par}{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is an item.
\end{itemize}

\RemoveFromAfterEndEnvironment{itemize}{bleat bleat\par}{}{}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is another item.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The third and fourth arguments of `\RemoveFromAfterEndEnviroment` are the same like third and fourth arguments of `\patchcmd`.

Comment: ...you should send a request to the package author.

Comment: @Werner: The user who needs it should do it …

Answer (score 10):

There might be an official way, but defining a new command `\AfterEndItemize` to specify what you want to do after `\end{itemize}`, and then use `\renewcommand` to change `\AfterEndItemize` to not do anything seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\AfterEndItemize}{bleat bleat}%
\AfterEndEnvironment{itemize}{\AfterEndItemize}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is an item.
\end{itemize}
%
\renewcommand{\AfterEndItemize}{}%
\begin{itemize}
\item This is another item.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way is: Use a boolean switch. Conveniently `etoolbox` provides such switches. Compare my question and the answers in [etoolbox: environment hooks in boolean switch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36167/etoolbox-environment-hooks-in-boolean-switch) and look at this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
  \doublespacing

\usepackage{etoolbox}
  \newbool{tightspace}
  \setbool{tightspace}{false} % that's the default state, so
                              % it's here only for clarity
%----------------------------%
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{itemize}{%
    \ifbool{tightspace}{% true part:
                        \begin{spacing}{0.9}
                       }{%
                         % false part empty - should do nothing
                        }%
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{itemize}{%
    \ifbool{tightspace}{% true part:
                        \end{spacing}
                       }{%
                         % false part
                        }%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \lipsum[1]
\end{itemize}


\begingroup
\setbool{tightspace}{true}

\verb|\setbool{tightspace}{true}| inside a group:

\begin{itemize}
  \item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
\endgroup


And from now all outside of groups:

Here is \verb|\setbool{tightspace}{false}| in effect:

\begin{itemize}
  \item \lipsum[3]
\end{itemize}


\verb|\setbool{tightspace}{true}|:
\setbool{tightspace}{true}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \lipsum[4]
\end{itemize}


And again \verb|\setbool{tightspace}{false}|:
\setbool{tightspace}{false}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \lipsum[5]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

use it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\End\end
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{itemize}{bleat bleat}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item This is an item.
\end{itemize}

\let\end\End 
\begin{itemize}
\item This is the last item.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you describe a bit how that works? Aren't there any interactions with other (possibly nested) environments or if one also patches another environment?

Comment: It is obvious that `etoolbox` does nothing with `\itemize` and `\enditemize`, otherwise the solution of the original poster would work. `etoolbox` redefines the `\end{itemize}`. If you want to have it local then simply put the one into a group.

Comment: I am asking because of the `\let\End\end` and `\let\end\End` trick, which generalized effects are not immediately clear to the uninspired. Would your trick also work if: (1) I am about to patch a second environment (`\AfterEndEnvironment{enumerate}{foo bar}`), which (2) in the document is used nested within the first, and (3) should be "undoable" independently from the first.

Comment: as I wrote, in that case you have to hold the undo locally

Answer (score 3):

My idea is that one should not do this, but rather define a new environment:

```
\newenvironment{itemizeplus}
  {\begin{itemize}}
  {\end{itemize}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{itemizeplus}{bleat bleat}
```

Thus the behavior of `itemize` and `itemizeplus` will be predictable throughout the document.

Note. A more efficient definition would be

```
\let\itemizeplus\itemize
\let\enditemizeplus\enditemize
\AfterEndEnvironment{itemizeplus}{bleat bleat}
```

or, perhaps better,

```
\let\itemizeplus\itemize
\def\enditemizeplus{\enditemize bleat bleat}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've expanded on @Schweinebacke's excellent answer in the event that others face the same problem that I have. **I'd like a single command that patches an environment and then ensures that the patch is removed after it is executed for the first time.** I've made some concessions in order to achieve this:

1. I need to associate an identifier with my hook
2. I will pollute the global namespace with generated `\csname`s
3. If I nest the environments, the hook will execute when the innermost
   environment ends and never again after.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

% Note  : Drop a particular code block from \AfterEnvEnvironment
% author: @Schweinebacke
% see   : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36770/59078
\newrobustcmd*{\RemoveFromAfterEndEnvironment}[2]{%
  \expandafter\patchcmd\csname @afterend@#1@hook\endcsname{#2}{}}

% Attach a (named) group to an environment that should be executed 
% the first time that an environment ends only once after the
% environment ends
%
% Arguments:
%   #1 - The environment to patch
%   #2 - A unique identifier for your hook
%   #3 - The group to be evaluated
%
% Example:
% \OnceAfterEndEnvironment{fooscope}{firstA}
%       {\stepcounter{foocounter}\thefoocounter}
\NewDocumentCommand\OnceAfterEndEnvironment{mmm}{{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname#2hook\endcsname{%
        % Evaluate the code block
        #3%
        % See Note [2]
        \edef\tmpargs{{#1}{\expandafter\noexpand\csname#2hook\endcsname}}%
        \expandafter\RemoveFromAfterEndEnvironment\tmpargs{}%
        % Drop the hook definition
        {\expandafter\gundef\csname#2hook\endcsname}%
    }%
    % Note [2]: Control expansion of the second argument to this function
    % Author  : @Qrrbrbirlbel
    % See     : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133759/59078
    \edef\tmpargs{{#1}\expandafter\noexpand\csname#2hook\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\AfterEndEnvironment\tmpargs{}%
}}
```

The following example demonstrates the usage. We create a simple environment `fooscope`, and a counter `foocounter` for demonstration. We register hooks
from outside and inside the environment, and modify the counter inside and
outside of the hooks. This test demonstrates the expected behavior of the
hooks.

```
\newenvironment{fooscope}
    {\par\textbf{fooscope-start}\par}
    {\par\textbf{fooscope-end}\par}
\newcounter{foocounter}
\setcounter{foocounter}{0}

\OnceAfterEndEnvironment{fooscope}{firstA}{\stepcounter{foocounter}\thefoocounter} %4
\begin{fooscope}
    first scope
    \stepcounter{foocounter} %1
    \stepcounter{foocounter} %2
    \OnceAfterEndEnvironment{fooscope}{firstB}{\stepcounter{foocounter}\thefoocounter} %5
    \stepcounter{foocounter} %3
\end{fooscope}
\vspace{1em}
\begin{fooscope}
    second scope
    \OnceAfterEndEnvironment{fooscope}{secondA}{\stepcounter{foocounter}\thefoocounter} %6
\end{fooscope}
\vspace{1em}
```

Which produces the following output. Note that the sequence of the counter values demonstrates the order in which the hooks were invoked.

[image: Example Rendering]

If possible, it'd be highly desirable to replace this with a version that did not require the user to pass in an identifier. I'm sure someone out there who has more expertise can do it.