# How do I have to invoke \expandafter for a macro with multiple arguments?

Tags: pstricks, expansion

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \pnodes{A}(-2,3)(3,4)(2,-1)(-2,-4)(-4,0)
    \def\points{(0,0)}
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,4}{%
            \pscircle*[linecolor=blue](A\x){3pt}%
            \xdef\points{\points+.2(A\x)}%
    }
    %The first line below causes errors.
    %\expandafter\nodexn{\points}{B}
    %\pscircle*[linecolor=red](B){3pt}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I have to invoke `\expandafter` for a macro with multiple arguments?

Comment: Does `\expandafter\nodexn\expandafter{\points}{B}` work? You're just expanding the `{` token (which stays `{`). The LaTeX kernel also defines `\@expandtwoargs` which would `\edef`s the first two arguments of a macro: `\@expandtwoargs\nodexn{\points}{B}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Yes. It works. Thank you! Now, what do I have to do? Delete this question or wait for your answer and then accept it?

Comment: Don't forget this trick if the argument you want to expand is at the end of a long list.  Just `\def` the list up to that point, and expandafter the `\def` and following `{`:  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\manyargs[4]{#1.#2.#3.\detokenize{#4}}
\def\expandthis{EXP}
\begin{document}
\manyargs{a}{b}{c}{\expandthis}

\def\tmp{\manyargs{a}{b}{c}}
\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\expandthis}
\end{document}
`  I learned that from David Carlisle.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I hope you don't mind that I have included your (or David's) trick in my answer. I've learned it by reading many sources where similar expansion tricks are often used.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel  Be my guest.  I can't lay claim to it.

Comment: with the `pst-node.tex` from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-node/ you can simply write `\nodexn{\points}{B}` without any `\expandafter`

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks, I just read  your comment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to do

```
\expandafter\nodexn\expandafter{\points}{B}
```

you need to "jump over" the `{` too otherwise

```
\expandafter\nodexn{\points}{B}
```

just expands `{` once (to `{`) before `\nodexn` gets expanded.

The LaTeX kernel defines a helpful macro `\@expandtwoargs` as

```
\def\@expandtwoargs#1#2#3{%
  \edef\reserved@a{\noexpand#1{#2}{#3}}\reserved@a}
```

which `\edef`s the first two arguments of a macro before "executing" it. Obviously, you would want to do something like

```
\makeatletter
\let\expandtwoargs\@expandtwoargs
\makeatother
```

to be able to use it comfortably. (And of course, this doesn't work for arguments that are not safely fully expandable.)

If you want to expand more than two arguments you can use a temporary macro which contains only the arguments:

```
\edef\tmp{{\argumentA}{\argumentB}{\argumentC}{\argumentD}}
```

which then only needs to be expanded once:

```
\expandafter\myMacro\tmp % \tmp already contains the braces
```

---

From the same trick box, but quite the opposite problem, namely to expand an argument at the end of a macro with many arguments, can be solved by stuffing everything up to the argument in a temporary macro which than can be "jumped over" very easily:

```
\def\B{B}
\def\tmp{\myMacro{argument A}{argument B}}
\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\argumentC}
```

Otherwise you would need to do

```
\expandafter\myMacro\expandafter{\expandafter a\expandafter r\expandafter g …
```

Comment: One more question based on my answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133657/19356) (locate the first code snippet at the top): Why don't I need `\expandafter` when invoking `\pstHomO` even though I use `\Points` as an argument?

Comment: Does that mean you can just drop the braces, i.e. that `\expandafter\nodexn\points{B}` would also work?

Comment: @Jonathan No, as `\nodexn` would than only grab the first two token of the expansion of `\points` (`(` and `0`) as its arguments instead of the expansion of `\points` as the first and `B` as the second argument.

Comment: @PGFTricks Unfortunately, I don’t know the exact syntax of `\pstHomO` (or what it actually does), but `\Points` only contains a list of things without `=`. Observe what happens if you do `\edef\Points{\Points,A2=1}` directly before `\pstHomO` and compare with `\pstHomO[…]{O}{\Points,A2=1}` (even though the `=1` is thrown away anway). The `=` is not properly parsed in the first case but in the second. (You may fix this with the following redefinition: `\def\@List#1{\xdef\@NewList{none}\expandafter\@List@i#1,\@nil\ignorespaces}`.)

Answer (score 14):

This is a comment on the more general topic raised in [Qrrbrbirlbel's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133759/4686) of selectively expanding one argument of a macro before executing the macro itself. I will take here "expanding" as meaning expanding once, and it is not assumed that the arguments are only single tokens (the expansion will be applied only to the first token of the argument; this could provoke further expansions among this argument of course). My comment is that it is possible to do this expandably.

**Nota Bene**: a more powerful such "`expandable expander`" has been added in an edit, below. It also expands only once the (first token of the) targeted argument but this can be promoted to a "full expansion". (see code)

We need these utilities:

```
\def\expandArg #1#2{\expandafter\expandArgaux\expandafter{#2}{#1}}
\def\expandArgaux #1#2{#2{#1}}
```

Then imagine I need to have the 3rd of the 5 arguments to `\mymacro` be expanded once before the execution of `\mymacro`:

```
\expandArg {\mymacro {Not me}{Not me}}{Expand Me}{Not me}{Not me}
```

does the trick. The difference with the trick mentioned in [Qrrbrbirlbel's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133759/4686) and in comments is that this is expandable in the sense of not needing a `\def`.

To illustrate:

```
\def\expandArg #1#2{\expandafter\expandArgaux\expandafter{#2}{#1}}
\def\expandArgaux #1#2{#2{#1}}

\tt
\def\mymacro #1#2#3#4#5{\meaning #3}
\def\x {\y}
\def\y {z}
\mymacro {1}{2}{\x}{4}{5}
\par
\expandArg {\mymacro {1}{2}}{\x}{4}{5}
\bye
```

Output:

> [image: expansion-trick]

I mentioned in a comment that it was also possible to have the more user-friendly syntax:

```
\ExpandNth {5}\mymacro{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}
```

without extra braces, thus, to expandably expand the fifth argument only, prior to the execution of `\mymacro`.

Here is one way. It acts correctly if given an `N` zero or less, but will create errors if `N` exceeds the actual number of arguments. It is also crucial that no spaces are left in-between the arguments of the macro `\mymacro` to which the expandable expander is applied.

```
\catcode`\_ 11

\def\ExpandNth #1%
{%
    \romannumeral0\ifnum #1>0
      \expandafter\ExpandNth_a
    \else
      \expandafter\ExpandNth_none
    \fi {#1}%
}
\def\ExpandNth_none #1{ }
\def\ExpandNth_a #1#2{\ExpandNth_b {#1}{#2}}
\def\ExpandNth_b #1%
{%
    \ifnum #1>1
      \expandafter\ExpandNth_c
    \else
      \expandafter\ExpandNth_w
    \fi {#1}%
}
\def\ExpandNth_c #1#2#3%
{%
    \expandafter\ExpandNth_b\expandafter
        {\the\numexpr #1-1}{#2{#3}}%
}%
\def\ExpandNth_w #1#2#3%
{%
    \expandafter\ExpandNth_z\expandafter {#3}{#2}%
}%
% replace #3 above by \romannumeral-`0#3 for "full" expansion

\def\ExpandNth_z #1#2{ #2{#1}}%

\catcode`\_ 8       

\tt

\def\mymacro #1#2#3#4#5{\meaning #1\par
                        \meaning #2\par
                        \meaning #3\par
                        \meaning #4\par
                        \meaning #5\par}
\def\a{\A} \def\A{A}
\def\b{\B} \def\B{B}
\def\c{\C} \def\C{C}
\def\d{\D} \def\D{D}
\def\e{\E} \def\E{E}

\hsize 12cm

Original \string\mymacro:\par
\mymacro \a\b\c\d\e

\medskip\hrule\medskip

With prior (once) expansion of the first argument:\par
\ExpandNth {1}\mymacro \a\b\c\d\e

\medskip\hrule\medskip

With prior (once) expansion of the second argument:\par
\ExpandNth {2}\mymacro \a\b\c\d\e

\medskip\hrule\medskip

With prior (once) expansion of the third argument:\par
\ExpandNth {3}\mymacro \a\b\c\d\e

\medskip\hrule\medskip

With prior (once) expansion of the fourth argument:\par
\ExpandNth {4}\mymacro \a\b\c\d\e

\medskip\hrule\medskip

With prior (once) expansion of the fifth argument:\par
\ExpandNth {5}\mymacro \a\b\c\d\e

\bye
```

Output:

> [image: selective expansion]

Comment: The user must be careful not to leave a space after `{\x}` in the `\expandArg` application above. We could define `\expandArg` with 3 arguments, and then the input would be `\expandArg {\mymacro ...}{Expand me}{all the rest}` and spaces would be allowed either before or after the `{Expand me}`.

Comment: It would  also be possible to construct a `\ExpandNth {n}` such that `\ExpandNth {5}\mymacro{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}` expands the fifth argument, with no need for the user to put extra braces,; still working "expandably". But this is more complicated.

Comment: Code has been edited to implement the macro mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: When I say that for `N>#args` errors are created this is not systematic: the effect is to expand the `Nth` token or braced material found and to reinject it within braces; and all those tokens in-between the last argument of the macro and the `Nth` spot will end up (each) in braces (or left unchanged if it was already `{..}` material).

Answer (score 4):

For this particular application you can simply do

```
\newcommand{\nodexnX}[1]{\expandafter\nodexn\expandafter{#1}}
```

and call `\nodexnX{\points}{B}`

Or you can go further and redefine `\nodexn` so that it fully expands its first argument

```
\let\PSTRICKSnodexn\nodexn
\renewcommand{\nodexn}[1]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
  \noexpand\PSTRICKSnodexn{#1}}\x
}
```

The LaTeX3 kernel has `\exp_args:Nx` that's implicitly added with `\cs_generate_variant:Nn`:

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \pstricks_nodexn:nn \nodexn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \pstricks_nodexn:nn { x }
\cs_set_eq:NN \nodexn \pstricks_nodexn:xn
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

If you need to fully expand also the second argument, you can do

```
\cs_set_eq:NN \pstricks_nodexn:nn \nodexn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \pstricks_nodexn:nn { xx }
\cs_set_eq:NN \nodexn \pstricks_nodexn:xx
```

In both case you have effectively redefined `\nodexn` to expand its argument(s) before the original macro is called.

---

#### Addition 2022

In the next LaTeX kernel, it will be available `\ExpandArgs` and

```
\ExpandArgs{x}\nodexn{\points}{B}
```

will do the trick. This is an interface to `\exp_args:Nx`, meaning that the next token is jumped over and the contents of the following braced group will be fully expanded.

You you want to fully expand also the second argument?

```
\ExpandArgs{xx}\nodexn{\points}{\foo}
```

will do.

So long as `\exp_args:N<characters>` exists, one can use `\ExpandArgs{<characters>}`. The characters are

- `N` to denote “jump over a token”
- `n` to denote “jump over a braced group”
- `x` to fully expand the contents of a braced group using `\edef`
- `e` to fully expand the contents of a braced group using `\expanded`
- `f` to recursively the contents of a braced group until finding an unexpandable token
- `o` to expand once the first token inside a braced group

If a needed particular combination does not exist, there is no “official“ user interface to create it, but one can do

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_args_generate:n { <characters>, ... }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Many combinations can be generated at once, separating the strings of characters by a comma.

Comment: Does "braced group" also work for `[arguments]` in square brackets?

Comment: @Eric No, this isn’t possible. Usually optional arguments ate grabbed and then processed at a lower level as n-type arguments.

Comment: The context here is trying to use `\subfix` (from `subfiles`) inside `\newmintinline` (from `minted`) as `\newmintinline[mylang]{\subfix{mylang.py}:MyLexer}`, and needing to ensure that `subfix` is immediately expanded. So I don't need to modify the expansion of the `[]` argument, but I do need to skip over it. Is this possible with `ExpandArgs`?

Comment: @Eric You can use `\expanded{\noexpand\newmintinline[mylang]{\subfix{mylang.py}:MyLexer}}`

Answer (score 0):

With [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package, tricky argument expansion can be replaced with intuitive function composition, which is similar to other programmming languages such as `Lua`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\usepackage{functional}
\Functional{scoping=true} % make every function become a group

\begin{document}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\PrgNewFunction \NodeXn { m m } {
  \nodexn {#1} {#2}
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \pnodes{A}(-2,3)(3,4)(2,-1)(-2,-4)(-4,0)
    \def\points{(0,0)}
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,4}{%
            \pscircle*[linecolor=blue](A\x){3pt}%
            \xdef\points{\points+.2(A\x)}%
    }
    \NodeXn{\Value\points}{B}
    \pscircle*[linecolor=red](B){3pt}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]