# nested environment with a star

Tags: environments, nesting, starred-version

I want to redefine an environment that include the environment alignat*.

I discovered that I can't do that :

```
\newenvironment{variables}
{  \paragraph{Variables :}

\begin{alignat*}{2} }
{  \end{endalignat*} }
```

so the solution I found is to use the command `\alignat` but this way, the equations are numebered and I won't.

```
\newenvironment{variables}
{  \paragraph{Variables :}

\alignat*{2} }
{  \endalignat* }
```

So how can I do to include `\alignat*` in my new environment keeping the star ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why define `\foo`? May be I missed something but you can inglude `\csname` inside the definitions

```
\newenvironment{variables}
  {\paragraph{Variables :}
   \csname alignat*\endcsname{2}}
  {\csname endalignat*\endcsname}
```

Comment: hmm actually you can (so +1:-) although it's less efficient in both space and time, although I was thinking when I wrote it that the environment detection trickery that the ams alignments do would require the command token exposed, but I think you're right that isn't actually needed here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think this has been the first tick I've borrowed from someone.

Comment: Beware, keep doing that and you'll turn into egreg, you wouldn't want that:-)

Answer (score 2):

`\csname endalignat*\endcsname` expands to the command `\endalignat*` that you can't normally type.  So `\foo` here is a helper macro that makes the environment definition that you intended except that the command names are passed as arguments `#1` and `#2`, then `\expandafter` is used to make the command names socthe construction is the same as

\foo{\alignedat*}{\endalignedat*}

but with * interpreted as part of the command name, as if it were a letter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}



\def\foo#1#2{%
\newenvironment{variables}
{\paragraph{Variables :}
#1{2}}
{#2}}
\expandafter\foo
  \csname alignat*\expandafter\endcsname
  \csname endalignat*\endcsname

\begin{document}

\begin{variables}
a&b\\
aaa&bbb
\end{variables}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain how does it work please ?

Comment: @Saroupille added some notes:-)

Comment: Ok thanks ! I just don't understand the `\expandafter` command. If we don't use it, what happens ?

Comment: @Saroupilleif you don't use it then it doesn't work:-) there is probably an answer on site explaining \expandafter I'll post a link

Comment: @Saroupille put \expandafter in the search box, lots of answers, perhaps start with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161064/how-does-your-mind-bend-expandafter-to-its-will

Comment: By the way, instead of `\csname endalignat*\endcsname` one can use more simply `\endalign`.

Comment: @egreg yes, I know, but I thought that would look even more weird (and is specific to those environments:-)