# expandafter and ifx

Tags: conditionals, expandafter

I try set color for only **first letter,** (`aaa` or `bbb`) in relation with test `\ifx`.
I have more complicated task in original, but I want to understand how it work on this simple example.
**My MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\begin{document}
\def\AAA{aaa}
\def\BBB{bbb}
\let\TST\AAA
\def\SETCOL #1{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\expandafter\SETCOL\ifx\TST\AAA\AAA\else\BBB\fi

\end{document}
```

With one `\expandafter` I have red-colored whole `aaa`

Comment: Maybe see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161064/how-does-your-mind-bend-expandafter-to-its-will?noredirect=1&lq=1. And obviously read TeXbook/TeX by Topic if you haven't, token manipulation is more than expandafter.

Answer (score 5):

Your code, after the action of `\expandafter`, leaves

```
\SETCOL\AAA\else\BBB\fi
```

and the argument to `\SETCOL` is `\AAA`, not the first letter.

Let's try with

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\SETCOL\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\TST\expandafter\AAA\AAA\else\BBB\fi
```

After the first `\expandafter` acts, you get

```
\expandafter\SETCOL\ifx\TST\AAA aaa\else\BBB\fi
```

and now you get

```
\SETCOL aaa\else\BBB\fi
```

In either case the tokens from `\else` to `\fi` disappear. However, if the test returns false, you have the same problem: when `\TST` is not `\ifx` equal to `\AAA`, the `\expandafter` nightmare would leave

```
\SETCOL\BBB\fi
```

You'd need to reach also `\BBB` if you want that `\SETCOL` sees the first token of the expansion of `\BBB`. Better use a different strategy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}

\begin{document}

\def\AAA{aaa}
\def\BBB{bbb}
\let\TST\AAA
\def\SETCOL #1{\expandafter\SETCOLAUX#1}
\def\SETCOLAUX #1{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\expandafter\SETCOL\ifx\TST\AAA\AAA\else\BBB\fi

\let\TST\BBB

\expandafter\SETCOL\ifx\TST\AAA\AAA\else\BBB\fi

\end{document}
```

[image]