# Problem with foreach loop through parameters

Tags: foreach

I have a problem with foreach loop. When I pass parameters as list with '/' used as separator it works really well. However when any element in that list is defined with \def the separator seems to not work and the strings are concatenated.

```
\newcommand{\testme}[1]{
\foreach \aa/\bb in {#1} { 
    |\aa| |\bb| \newline
    }
}

\def\testmedef{{xyz}/{XYZ}}

\testme{
    {abc}/{CDE},
    \testmedef%
}
```

Result:

```
|abc|CDE|
|xyz/XYZ|xyz/XYZ|
```

Thank you for your kind help!

Comment: (if you want to read more, this is special case 4 of my question [verbatim - Why can't I use <some macro> inside the argument of <some other macro>? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645995/why-cant-i-use-some-macro-inside-the-argument-of-some-other-macro) , where the outer macro does not expand the inner one) ■

Comment: There's also a TikZ specific solution  
which is probably the best in this case as long as the inner content is unexpandable https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648813/250119 ■ Or use `ExpandArgs` [pstricks - How do I have to invoke \expandafter for a macro with multiple arguments? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133753/how-do-i-have-to-invoke-expandafter-for-a-macro-with-multiple-arguments/133779#133779)

Comment: Side note, you're using `%` at exactly the wrong locations. See [symbols - What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the linked question

Comment: Thanks guys, great reads there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call:

```tex
\newcommand{\testme}[1]{
\foreach \aa/\bb in {#1} { 
    |\aa| |\bb| \newline
    }
}

\def\testmedef{{xyz}/{XYZ}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_set_eq:NN \expandx \exp_args:Nx
\ExplSyntaxOff
\def\testmedef{{xyz}/{XYZ}}
\expandx\testme{abc/CDE,\testmedef}
```

Comment: Wrong order. OP's def is the second item

Comment: Thank you, the \expandx worked magic. Now if I only knew what does it do :)

Comment: @goki Documentation of that particular one is in interface3.pdf; in general there is [macros - Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined/)